# determinant of a tricky matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm doing a research on matrix [integrators](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379507001620) and I ran into a problem in one particular case. To finish my proof the last thing remaining is to prove the nonsingularity of a specific matrix $$M_n: (m_{ij} = \frac{1}{a_i - a_j}, 1\leq i \leq n, 1\leq j \leq n,i\neq j;m_{ii} = \frac{c}{a_i - b} + \sum\limits_{k\neq i, 1\leq k \leq n}\frac{1}{a_i - a_k}),$$
where all $a_i, b$ are distinct.

To be more clear I provide $$M_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{c}{a_1 -b} + \frac{1}{a_1 - a_2} && \frac{1}{a_1 - a_2}\\
\frac{1}{a_2 - a_1} && \frac{c}{a_2 -b} + \frac{1}{a_2 - a_1}
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$M_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{c}{a_1 -b} + \frac{1}{a_1 - a_2} + \frac{1}{a_1 - a_3} && \frac{1}{a_1 - a_2} && \frac{1}{a_1 - a_3}\\
\frac{1}{a_2 - a_1} && \frac{c}{a_2 -b} + \frac{1}{a_2 - a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2 - a_3} && \frac{1}{a_2 - a_3}\\
\frac{1}{a_3 - a_1} && \frac{1}{a_3 - a_2} && \frac{c}{a_3 - b} + \frac{1}{a_3 - a_1} + \frac{1}{a_3 - a_2}
\end{pmatrix}$$

For $n \leq 7$ I calculated the $det(M_n) = \frac{c(c+1)...(c + n -1)}{\prod\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}(a_i - b)}$, but I have no idea how to prove this in general case.

I my particular case $c\in \mathbb N$, so this formula will prove the nonsingularity of $M_n$.

Any ideas and tips to prove the formula, or even to prove nonsingularity of $M_n$ in some other way - are very appreciated

Comment: dont know whether this helps but if you multiply the matrix by its transpose you should get a symmetrical matrix

Comment: If $D_0 := \operatorname{diag}((a_i-b)^{-1})$ and $M_0 := M-cD_0$, then$$M = M_0 + cD_0 = D_0(D_0^{-1}M_0 + cI) = (M_0D_0^{-1}+cI)D_0.$$Therefore,$$\det M = \det(D_0)\cdot\det(D_0^{-1}M_0 + cI) = \det(D_0)\cdot\det(M_0D_0^{-1}+cI).$$Now, $\det(D_0)$ is your denominator. Thus, you basically have to show that $0,1,\ldots,n-1$ are the eigenvalues of $M_0D_0^{-1}$ or $D_0^{-1}M_0$ (which have the same eigenvalues anyways). Maybe it makes sense to find the eigenvectors of that matrix. One could start with finding an element in the kernel.

Comment: Mathematica confirms your conjecture for $n=4$ and $n=5$. But for $n=5$ it takes about 1 minute on my laptop.

Comment: I found the eigenvector for $D_0^{-1}M_0$ with respect to $\ell = 0,\ldots,n-1$. It is $v\in\mathbb R^n$ with$$v_k = \frac{(b-a_k)^\ell}{(b-a_n)^\ell}\prod_{j=1,j\neq k}^{n-1}\frac{a_j-a_n}{a_j-a_k},\quad k=1,\ldots,n-1$$and $v_n=-1$.

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful simplification. It now sounds a lot easier. I will now explore the properties of $D_0^{-1}M_0$

Comment: @SaveMyLife Puh, I got these vectors from experiments with Mathematica up to n = 5. So, I cannot guarantee that they are correct. I cannot even see in general that the one for $\ell=0$ is a nullspace vector. I tried a lot of manipulations, but too many sums and products...

Comment: I think the given matrix is a type of the [Cauchy-like matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is a development of ideas from the comments of [amsmath](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/487169/amsmath). The decisive step forward is derivation of the equation $(7)$ below.

Given a set of $n$ pairs of complex numbers
$$\{(x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_2),\dots,(x_n,y_n)\}$$ such that
$$
\forall\; i\ne j:\; x_i\ne x_j,
$$
define its [interpolating polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) as
$$
y(x)=\sum_{i}y_i\prod_{k\ne i}\frac{x-x_k}{x_i-x_k}.\tag1
$$

Differentiating the expression over $x$ and evaluating the result at $x_i$ one obtains:
$$
y'_i\equiv y'(x_i)=\sum_{j\ne i}\frac1{x_i-x_j}
\left[y_i-y_j\prod_{k\ne(i,j)}\frac{x_i-x_k}{x_j-x_k}\right].\tag2
$$
or
$$
\frac{y'_i}{\prod\limits_{k\ne i}x_i-x_k}
=\sum_{j\ne i}\frac1{x_i-x_j}\left[\frac{y_i}{\prod\limits_{k\ne i}x_i-x_k}
+\frac{y_j}{\prod\limits_{k\ne j}x_j-x_k}\right].\tag{2a}
$$
Introducing $f_i=\frac{y_i}{\prod\limits_{k\ne i}x_i-x_k}$, $f'_i=\frac{y'_i}{\prod\limits_{k\ne i}x_i-x_k}$ the equation $(\text{2a})$ can be rewritten in matrix notation as:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum\limits_{i\ne1}\frac{1}{x_1-x_i}& \frac1{x_1-x_2}&\cdots&\frac1{x_1-x_n}\\
\frac1{x_2-x_1}& \sum\limits_{i\ne2}\frac{1}{x_2-x_i}&\cdots&\frac1{x_2-x_n}\\
\vdots& \vdots& \ddots&\vdots\\
\frac1{x_n-x_1}&\frac1{x_n-x_2}&\cdots&\sum\limits_{i\ne n}\frac{1}{x_n-x_i}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\vphantom{\sum\limits_{i\ne1}\frac{1}{x_1-x_i}}f_1\\
\vphantom{\sum\limits_{i\ne1}\frac{1}{x_1-x_i}}f_2\\
\vdots\\
\vphantom{\sum\limits_{i\ne1}\frac{1}{x_1-x_i}}f_n\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\vphantom{\sum\limits_{i\ne1}\frac{1}{x_1-x_i}}f'_1\\
\vphantom{\sum\limits_{i\ne1}\frac{1}{x_1-x_i}}f'_2\\
\vdots\\
\vphantom{\sum\limits_{i\ne1}\frac{1}{x_1-x_i}}f'_n\\
\end{pmatrix}.\tag3
$$
or
$$
A f=f'.\tag4
$$

Assume now a special form of the interpolating polynomial:
$$
y_l(x)=(\lambda x+\beta)^l,\quad
\beta,\lambda\in\mathbb C,\,\lambda\ne 0;\; l\in\mathbb Z,\,0\le l<n,
$$
with corresponding $f$-vector components
$$
f_{li}=\frac{(\lambda x_i+\beta)^l}{\prod\limits_{k\ne i}x_i-x_k},\quad
f'_{li}=\frac{\lambda l(\lambda x_i+\beta)^{l-1}}{\prod\limits_{k\ne i}x_i-x_k}.\tag5
$$

Substituting the vectors $f_l$ and $f'_l$ into $(4)$ and multiplying both sides of the resulting equation from the left by diagonal matrix $D$ with elements
$$
D_{ii}=\lambda x_i+\beta,\tag6
$$
one obtains:
$$
DA f_l=\lambda l f_l.\tag7
$$

From this one concludes that $f_l$ are the eigenvectors of the matrix $DA$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\epsilon_l=\lambda l$. Observe that we have found all $n$ (distinct) eigenvalues of the matrix.

Since the determinant of the matrix $DA+Iz$ is [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) of the matrix $-DA$, one obtains:
$$\begin{align}
&\det (DA+I z)=\prod_{l=0}^{n-1} z+\lambda l\tag8\\
&\implies 
\det (A+D^{-1}z)=\det{D^{-1}}\det (DA+Iz)
=\prod_{l=0}^{n-1}\frac{z+\lambda l}{\lambda x_{l+1}+\beta}.\tag9
\end{align}
$$

It remains only to observe that $A+D^{-1}z$ with $\lambda=1$, $\beta=-b$, $z=c$, $x_i=a_i$ is exactly your matrix $M$.